# Including AndroidManifest.xml in a Unity3D build causes mobile application to instantly crash

Tags: android, xml, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I have an issue where the inclusion of an AndroidManifest.xml file in a android build of a Unity3D project causes the application to instantly crash upon opening. However not including the file causes the application to not be able to access the internet. I'm not very familiar with the structure of manifest xml files so any help would be greatly appreciated.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.DefaultCompany.DynamoDB"
      android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

  <supports-screens
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true"/>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


  <permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


  <application
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
      android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:debuggable="true">

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>


  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you add build log, what exactly error are You facing?

Answer (score 0):

try `UnityPlayerActivity` instead

> `UnityPlayerNativeActivity`

and check this package name `package="com.DefaultCompany.DynamoDB"` . maybe it should be `package="com.amazonaws.unity"`